# Trying to import xml into Google Sheet but not pulling any data

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to pull the "followers" from this page https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/two19/kingless into a google sheet using the `importxml` function.

This isn't pulling any data back:

```
=importxml("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/two19/kingless", "//span[@class='type-14 block text-center text-left-md']")
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided link [https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/two19/kingless](http://%20https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/two19/kingless) is not initially loaded the **"follower"** detail at begin, so you wouldn't get the detail through **importxml** function.

Comment: Interesting. Is there another approach I could take to pull this figure?

Comment: Quite impossible due to the access of the detail is protected by token for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, it is not possible to be scraped. all you can get is:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/two19/kingless"); 5000; 20)
```